# how to call a method in a tab view Controller from appdelegate. story board

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to select an index on a tab from the app delegate and call a function in the view controller that the tab is mapped to in the story board

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

     NSString *alertMessage = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];

    if (alertMessage != nil){
         UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabb.selectedIndex = 2;
     // Need to call a method in my SpecialsViewController which manages properties and functions of tab with index 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *controller = [tabb.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index_of_your_view_ SpecialsViewController];
[controller call_your_method];
```

In your case `index_of_your_view_ SpecialsViewController = 2`

Comment: UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
                
                tabb.delegate=self;
                
                UIViewController *controller =[tabb.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
                
                if(controller !=nil){
                    [controller   LoadSpecialsWebsite];    
                }

Comment: Heres my code in AppDelegate.m but I am getting this error:
-[UINavigationController LoadSpecialsWebsite]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

      UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
                
       
                UIViewController *controller =[tabb.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
                
                if(controller !=nil){
                    [controller   LoadSpecialsWebsite];    
                }

//SpecialsViewController.m
      -(void) LoadSpecialsWebsite{
       NSLog(@"LoadSpecialsWebsite");

        }

Comment: Ok do the following 
 UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController; UINavigationController *controller =[tabb.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]; if(controller !=nil){ [controller.viewControllers.lastObject LoadSpecialsWebsite]; } //SpecialsViewController.m -(void) LoadSpecialsWebsite{ NSLog(@"LoadSpecialsWebsite"); }